# How to turn a Python file into exe [Python34]

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

I've got a problem here I don't know how to turn a Python script into an exe file.
I tried using py2exe but the latest version they got is 2.6 and I need something that will work for version 34 (Which is the latest version of Python).

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Did you try searching on Google?

Comment: @Hidde: StackOverflow is *the destination* for google. If you know about the duplicate question on SO then post a link

Answer (score 1):

use **[cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)**, as you can see from its site, cx_freeze is compatible with Python 3.

And I really like its [documentation](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: If this really helped then please accept the answer, it will let other users to know that this question is solved.